# UITableViewCell resort without whole table reload

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I now have some table with some custom cells in it. It' can be scrolled, cells provide some information and can interact with user with some buttons and so on.

Is where any way to resort the cells with some animation without whole table reload?

for example I have cells with tags 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - placed as I wrote here. I want to resort it to become 2,5,1,3,4 for example - and user must see the cells moving to it's new place - but without table reload. Now I have to reload the table - so there is no any visual animation and to user it can be hard to understand what there is go on...

Comment: Did you try [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; method?

Comment: yes. it provide some level of user expirience of cause, but not fully enough for me... I need to have more - I need what 1 cell visually moved to 3 position and so on - it'll be much better for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I complete with my own question, thanks to Laura for provide me help where I found the way to do what I want. The main point of it - to use

```
[_tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:indFrom toIndexPath:indTo];
```

for it. There is exist some not easy things here with indexPaths of items currently not visible on screen, but main thing - cell move - os ok.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this question will help you:

[UITableView animate row reordering upon sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071380/uitableview-animate-row-reordering-upon-sort)

You probably cannot use the tag for each TableCell, but I cannot see how you get your data for your cells so can't help you much there. If you use a model, you could add a field to define the sorting order.

Hope this helps you in the right direction!

Comment: Laura, thanks, you answer guide me to the right way, now I complete with it.